# How to run a Python program ona specific CPU core

Tags: python, unix, cpu-cores

Say I have a python file - **file1.py** with arg **--in**

`python file1.py --in 10`

I have an 8-core Unix machine, I want to run the same script 8 times (infinite loop) (diff --in value) which should run in 8 different cores, like

`python file1.py --in 10` --> in core 1

`python file1.py --in 20` --> in core 2

`python file1.py --in 130` --> in core 3

.. so on

How to implement this? How do I specify which core to run?

`python file1.py --in 10 &`

`python file1.py --in 20 &`

`python file1.py --in 130 &`

If I run it like this, will it run on the same core or different cores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taskset

```
taskset -c 1 python file1.py --in 10
taskset -c 2 python file1.py --in 20
taskset -c 3 python file1.py --in 130
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response! inside python file is there any way to see which core it's running?